# simple sliding window filter in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filter, sliding-window

I don't have the package for `nlfilter` and I didn't quite follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202463/sliding-window-algorithm-for-activiting-recognition-matlab).

I have a really simple function `fun` and I want to apply it to a moving window of an array. The array is `Nx1`, and I want to look at length `k` intervals, say. So for `N=10` and `k=3` and `fun = @(x) min(x);` I would get

```
A = [13 14 2 14 10 3 5 9 15 8];

filter(A,k,fun) = [2 2 2 3 3 3 5 8];
```

Here I only want to look at indices 1,2,3 then 2,3,4 then ... then 8,9,10, so the final sequence is length 7. I can do this easy with a for loop, but I have no idea how to vectorize it for Matlab. Help, please. Thanks.

Comment: If you were looking for the minimum inside a window, you could use `imerode`, but unfortunately, that's in the image processing toolbox as well.

Comment: another similar question with some good answers: [How do I select n elements of a sequence in windows of m ? (matlab)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099590/how-do-i-select-n-elements-of-a-sequence-in-windows-of-m-matlab)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one very simple and fast way to do it:

```
>> min([A(1:(end-2)); A(2:(end-1)); A(3:end)], [], 1)

ans =

     2     2     2     3     3     3     5     8
```

EDIT: Since you want a full function...

```
function running_min = running_min(x, k)

xrep = repmat(x, 1, k);
xrep = reshape([xrep zeros(1, k)], length(x)+1, k);
running_min = min(xrep, [], 2)';
running_min = running_min(1:end-k);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only works for the example above when k=3. I need a function that takes k as an input.

Comment: Downvote? The extension is trivial. I thought I'd leave that to you. See edit above.

Comment: I didn't downvote (I don't even think I can). The extension isn't obvious to me. Thanks for elaborating. I still don't see how to input an arbitrary vector function, but this helps a lot. Thanks.

Comment: No worries...it's totally my mistake. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

The [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202463/sliding-window-algorithm-for-activiting-recognition-matlab/2203332#2203332) you mentioned gave a general solution for building sliding windows (you could control: overlapping vs. distinct, slide step, overlap amount, windows size)

In your case, it is much simpler and can be easily performed with the [HANKEL](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hankel.html&ei=6Me5Tq2LN4KIhQf53umhBw&usg=AFQjCNEOJBamxmJ1vNb_1zsQ9YBFSFq96g&sig2=51yhB_gcJgAv3YYKWugKpg) function:

```
x = [13 14 2 14 10 3 5 9 15 8];
idx = hankel(1:3, 3:length(x))
min( x(idx) )
```

---

If you want to build a reusable solution:

```
function y = myFilter(x,k,fcn)
    idx = hankel(1:k, k:length(x));
    y = cellfun(fcn, num2cell(x(idx),1));
end
```

which we use as:

```
x = [13 14 2 14 10 3 5 9 15 8];
y = myFilter(x, 3, @(x)min(x))
```

Note I am using CELLFUN in case `fcn` cannot operate across dimensions in a vectorized manner...