# MATLAB function to process vector with sliding window function, return matrix of vector responses

Tags: matlab, sliding-window

Assuming vector `v` of size `1 x n` and function `fun` that takes in a vector of length `L` and returns a vector of size `p x 1`.

Is there a MATLAB function that would take in vector `v`, process each sliding window of length `L` with function fun, and return a matrix of size `p x n` (or `p x (n-L)`).

I am aware this could be achieved with creating a matrix of windowed vectors with `im2col` and processing each of those, but this takes too much memory for a long vector `v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
funsl=@(is) fun(v(is:is+l-1));
cell2mat(arrayfun(funsl,1:length(v)-l+1,'UniformOutput',false))
```

What I did here is define an anonymous function that, for a fixed `v` and `l` and a starting index parameter (`is`), gets the respective slice of `v` and applies `fun` to it.

Then this function is applied, via `arrayfun`, to all useful values for this starting index. For reasons I myself cannot quite name at the moment, each application returns a `p x 1` vector, but `arrayfun` cannot arrange it into a proper matrix, thus the UniformOutput=false setting and the `cell2mat` call around it.

**Edit**: To test this with a function that turns 1-by-5 vectors into 4-by-1 vectors I used

```
l=5;v=1:12; fun=@(x) cumsum(x(2:end))';
```

and got this result:

```
ans =

 2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
 5     7     9    11    13    15    17    19
 9    12    15    18    21    24    27    30
14    18    22    26    30    34    38    42
```

Note again that in the definition of `funsl` `v` is fixed, To apply this approach to different `v` you could make another function that takes `v` (and `l`, if you do not want to fix this) as parameter(s), contains the two lines above and returns the result of the second one.

Answer (score 1):

The same solution from this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974616/simple-sliding-window-filter-in-matlab/8058977#8058977) could apply (with some modifications):

```
n = 7; L = 3;
v = rand(1,n);                        %# 1-by-n vector
M = num2cell(v(hankel(1:L,L:n)),1);   %# sliding windows of length L
fcn = @(x)[min(x);max(x);sum(x)];     %# function that takes a vector of length L
                                      %# and returns a p-by-1 vector (p=3)
%# apply function to sliding windows, result is a p-by-(n-L+1) matrix
M = cell2mat(cellfun(fcn, M, 'UniformOutput',false));
```